# Build Policy using JIRA with TFS

Tags: git, jira

TFS or Visual Studio Team Services has the possibility to define a branch policy on Git repositories, so that pull requests are required to have a work item linked before they can be merged.

Is there any way to implement a similar policy while using JIRA for issue tracking?

Comment: To clarify, do you want JIRA transitions blocked by git workflow, or do you want GitHub / Bitbucket PRs blocked by JIRA workflow?

Comment: None of this. I want to be able to be able to enforce a build policy on TFS that TFS PRs require a JIRA issue linked (instead of a TFS work item). I added the TFS tags to the question to make this clear, since essentially this is a TFS question, but unfortunately they were removed through edits even though I tried to reject them which no make the question less clear.

Answer (score 0):

No, you would not be able to link to Jira.

That said, you could emulate that link quite easily. If you create a second Build in VSTS that runs a single task that validates the Jira link you can then use the API to add a second build policy to your branch. Both your CI build, and your "Jira link validating" build would need to pass to be able to merge.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/policy/overview

While the UI does not support being able to add multiple Build Policies to a Branch you can do it through the API.